# Conditional Custom field with foreach

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

i use use this code to set slider in header with CF, how i can disable when CF is empty or set another CF key to exclude it?

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);//Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['slider_id'];//key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
  echo get_new_royalslider($value) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less code lines with `get_post_custom_values()`

```
$values = get_post_custom_values('slider_id', $post_id);

// if non-empty
if($values) {
    foreach($values as $value)
        echo get_new_royalslider($value);
}
```

If `$values` array is empty, nothing happens.

Comment: thanks Max and sorry for my english, your code it's ok and run, i add "else" for original slider, because in category or post_custom of my theme i don't have custom_field!! and  i don't know how activate this!!                                                                     $values = get_post_custom_values('slider_id', $post_id);

// if non-empty
if($values) {
    foreach($values as $value)
        echo get_new_royalslider($value);
} else { echo tfuse_header_content('header');}                tnks a lot!!!! are you super

Comment: sam80it, if everything is OK, please accept the answer to make it "answered" so other people can easily find it.

Comment: @sam80it, check [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667)